# How to use a variable within a formula?

Tags: excel, merge, excel-formula

How can I merge different excel files (different in file name and values inside the sheet) with the same format in one excel file by a variable which is the name of the workbook ?

I can't change the name between the brackets for example `='[P2106.xlsm]management samenvatting'!B2` i would like the `p2106` as a **variable** which refers to the **cell** that is the name of the workbook

I've tried cutting the formula in parts and then put it like `='[ & variable(cell) &xlsm]management samenvatting'!B2` , but this gives back the cell names nog the value that the formula should give. when I then copied the formula in word and back in excel the value from the formula appears.

I don't know what to do any more if there is someone who could help me thank you for that.

Comment: that's my fault `W = H`. He wants to use a cell reference within a formula

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are not seen as text qualifier by Excel, only double quotes are regarded as such.

For what you want to do, build a formula from pieces of text you will have to use the INDIRECT formula, with double quotes around all the text parts:

```
=INDIRECT("='[" & variable(cell) & ".xlsm]management samenvatting'!B2")
```

Off course `variable(cell)` needs to be further specified by yourself...

You were almost there.

Indeed as mehow commented, this only works with opened workbooks. If you want to do it with closed workbooks you can use VBA scripts.

Comment: one drawback is that it does not work with closed workbooks. There is a `.` missing before the `xlsm`